# Extract Links Address from HTML codes using PHP

Tags: php

i have code to get json from url and convert it to csv
but im geting html tags output so how i can rempve all tags like  remove to "span","a" but keep the links only

remove everything except the links

```
<span class="file file-ffd--pdf file--appli-pdf"><a href="http://mysite.o/sites/default/files/2021-02/goof%20Patient%20num%20Card%20En.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=735062">goof Patient num Card En.pdf</a></span>
, <span class="file file--ffs-application-pdf file--appli-pdf"><a href="http://mysite.o/sites/default/files/2021-02/goof%20Patient%20num%20Card%20V%204.0.1%20Ar-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=167085">goof Patient num Card Ar.pdf</a></span>
```

the result is

```
http://mysite.o/sites/default/files/2021-02/goof%20Patient%20num%20Card%20En.pdf
http://mysite.o/sites/default/files/2021-02/goof%20Patient%20num%20Card%20V%204.0.1%20Ar-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84.pdf
```

I need to remove all html tags and text but to keep the links.

Edit: here is my code

```
<?php
//products json
$uri = 'http://my.site/RM_json';
$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'=>'GET', 
    'header'=>'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',)
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$jsondata = file_get_contents($uri, false, $context);
 if($jsondata === false){
        $error = error_get_last();
        echo $error['message'];
    }

$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsondata, true); 

array_walk_recursive($jsonDecoded, function (&$val) { $val = strip_tags($val); });

$file = 'fileout.csv';
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
fprintf($fh, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));

    fputcsv($fh,["title", "field_risk_minimization_type","field_risk_1","field_hcpg","field_patient_card","field_healthcare_provider_checkl","field_dhpc"]);

if (is_array($jsonDecoded)) {
    
  foreach ($jsonDecoded as $line) {

    if (is_array($line)) {
        
          
      fputcsv($fh,$line);
    }
  }
}
fclose($fh);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
readfile($file);
?>
```

json data

```
[{"title":"(Actemra\u00ae(Tocilizumab","field_tags":"Healthcare professionals, Patients","field_risk_minimization_type":"Patient Card, Direct Healthcare Professional Communication DHPC, Healthcare provider guide, patient guide","field_drug_class":"Immunosuppressant","field_hcpg":"\u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Actemra%20HCP%20Brochure.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=455657\u0022\u003EActemra HCP Brochure.pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n","field_patient_card":"\u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Actemra%20Patient%20Alert%20Card%20English.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=735062\u0022\u003EActemra Patient Alert Card English.pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n, \u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Actemra%20Patient%20Alert%20Card%20V%204.0.1%20Arabic-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=167085\u0022\u003EActemra Patient Alert Card V 4.0.1 Arabic-\u0645\u062d\u0648\u0644.pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n","field_risk_1":"\u003Cp\u003ESafety information about the\u00a0 Administration\u003C\/p\u003E","field_risk_minimization_type_1":"Patient Card, Direct Healthcare Professional Communication DHPC, Healthcare provider guide, patient guide","field_tags_1":"\u003Ca href=\u0022\/en\/taxonomy\/term\/48\u0022 hreflang=\u0022en\u0022\u003EHealthcare professionals\u003C\/a\u003E, \u003Ca href=\u0022\/en\/taxonomy\/term\/49\u0022 hreflang=\u0022en\u0022\u003EPatients\u003C\/a\u003E","field_specialty_theraputic_area_":"Rheumatology","field_healthcare_provider_checkl":"","field_dhpc":"\u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Actemra%20DHCPL.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=92901\u0022\u003EActemra DHCPL.pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n, \u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Actemra%C2%AEDHPC.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=516304\u0022\u003EActemra\u00aeDHPC.pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n"},{"title":"(Simponi\u00ae(Golimumab","field_tags":"Healthcare professionals, Patients","field_risk_minimization_type":"Patient Card","field_drug_class":"Immunosuppressant","field_hcpg":"\u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Simponi%C2%AE%20HCP%20guide%20.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=181876\u0022\u003ESimponi\u00ae HCP guide .pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n","field_patient_card":"\u003Cspan class=\u0022file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022http:\/\/my.site\/sites\/default\/files\/2021-02\/Simponi%C2%AEpatient%20card%20ara.pdf\u0022 type=\u0022application\/pdf; length=1146512\u0022\u003ESimponi\u00aepatient card ara.pdf\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n","field_risk_1":"\u003Cp\u003E\u00a0.Safety information about risk of Hepatitis B reactivation, Congestive Heart Failure and\u00a0Serious hypersentivity and infections\u00a0\u003C\/p\u003E","field_risk_minimization_type_1":"Patient Card","field_tags_1":"\u003Ca href=\u0022\/en\/taxonomy\/term\/48\u0022 hreflang=\u0022en\u0022\u003EHealthcare professionals\u003C\/a\u003E, \u003Ca href=\u0022\/en\/taxonomy\/term\/49\u0022 hreflang=\u0022en\u0022\u003EPatients\u003C\/a\u003E","field_specialty_theraputic_area_":"Rheumatology","field_healthcare_provider_checkl":"","field_dhpc":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple choices to handle this issue

**1- using regular expressions in PHP**

**2- using DOM handle in PHP**

1- here is a simple function that handle your need as well using Regular Expression:

```
function linkExtractor($html)
{
 $linkArray = array();
 if(preg_match_all('/<a\s+.*?href=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
  foreach ($matches as $match) {
   array_push($linkArray, array($match[1], $match[2]));
  }
 }
 return $linkArray;
}
```

pass your variable that contains html and get back links as array
review main source [here](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/extract-links-html-file-php)

in your case , you can add above function in your code and change this line

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

to this:

```
$jsonDecoded = linkExtractor( $jsondata );
```

2- you can also use DOM to handle your need as well
[here](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) is a php class for handle DOM as you want
there is sample usage that you can check them
you can extract a tag or even an attribute of a tag as you want

**update:**

since we have needed array using `linkExtractor` function , so don't need to use `json_decode` function, i made some changes in above code

**update 2:**

also you can remove `array_walk_recursive($jsonDecoded, function (&$val) { $val = strip_tags($val); });` since there is no html tags in `$jsonDecoded`

Comment: hanks for your replay, im getting error ( <b>Warning</b>: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>/var/www/html/sfdasolar/GetRMMList.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />) the line 29 is $jsonDecoded = json_decode( linkExtractor( $jsondata ) , true); 
by the way...the link is not html its json...but it have some html tags

Comment: oh yeah! you have to change `$jsonDecoded = json_decode( linkExtractor( $jsondata ) , true); ` to '$jsonDecoded = linkExtractor( $jsondata );'  since you no need to any json! since first param of  `array_walk_recursive` need an array and result of `linkExtractor` function is an array

Comment: also you can comment `array_walk_recursive($jsonDecoded, function (&$val) { $val = strip_tags($val); });` since there is no html tags in `$jsonDecoded`